# Can I customize the columns that are displayed on the Manage Events page?

Tags: civievent, column

IS there anyway that I can modify the table that is displayed on the Manage Events page.  Ideally I'd like to be able to change the columns that are displayed.  I couldn't see where this can be done in the admin/config menu but can this be done by editing the relevant page template?  If so can someone provide me with details as to which file needs to be edited? thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change that display by writing some code using [hook_civicrm_searchColumns](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_searchColumns)

The template is CRM/Event/Form/Selector.tpl but you may not need to change that.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll give it a try and see how i go!!

Comment: This seems like it should be correct - but that hook isn't triggered on the "Manage Events" page, unfortunately.